# GroovyConsole running build.gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, groovy-console

GradleWare's book - **[Building and Testing with Gradle](http://www.gradleware.com/registered/books/building-and-testing/hello-gradle.html)** - states the following in section 1.1: 
**"Every Gradle build file is an executable Groovy script."**

However, when I run a build.gradle file in GroovyConsole, it gives me this error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   build.apply() is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[plugin:android-library]] Possible
>   solutions: any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), every(),
>   every(groovy.lang.Closure), split(groovy.lang.Closure)    at
>   build.run(build.gradle:1)

It refers to line 1:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

In the build script:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 14
  buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'

  sourceSets {
    main {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
      java.srcDirs = ['src']
      res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
  }
}
```

So can you please clarify whether the book's statement is correct or wrong??

Thank you,
Igor Ganapolsky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement isn't to be taken literally. A Gradle script cannot be run with plain Groovy, just like a Javascript snippet on a web page cannot be run in a plain JavaScript engine outside the browser.

Comment: If the stmt cannot be taken literally, then how can it be taken: metaphorically or symbolically??  JavaScript can easily be run outside the browser with Node.js!

Comment: You didn't get my point. A Gradle build script is like JavaScript code that uses the DOM and other browser APIs, and therefore cannot run outside the browser.

Comment: It all depends on how you define "executable Groovy script". Is it a Groovy script? Yes. Is it executable? Yes. Can it be run in any environment? No.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for explaining.  I think that piece of documentation can be misleading for beginners in Gradle...

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to add a task to a gradle build file to launch a Groovy Console, though, as described here:

http://piraguaconsulting.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/gradle-groovy-console.html

The relevant code snippet is:

```
task(console, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
   main = 'groovy.ui.Console'
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A gradle build file is strictly spoken not groovy.
It is a scripting language, aka a DSL (domain specific language) **written** in groovy. Hence you need the gradle distribution to run any gradle file, see: https://gradle.org/install/

Comment: Android Studio comes with Gradle

Comment: But he is running it in GroovyConsole, hence he has to import the relevant graddle classes, aka adding the *.jars to the class path.